# Change 'lastline' display character (@@@)

Tags: options

You can set `display` to `lastline` to see "`@@@`" at the end of the last line when it doesn't fit the screen. I'd prefer to use a different character for that purpose, such as `...` or `---`.

Is there a way to change the character used?

Comment: It's currently not possible to change this without editing the source and recompiling.

Comment: Vim issue for this: [Make 'display' lastline (aka @@@) customizable](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10963)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Vim 9.0.0656 (Oct 2022) you can use `lastline` in the `fillchars` setting; for example to change it to `·`:

```
:set fillchars=lastline:·
```

Answer (score -1):

vim handle spaces tab and return lien by:

```
set list

set listchars=space:-
set listchars+=tab:>-
set listchars+=eol:¶
```

to pick the last line and add `@` or `¶` at the end you can use
`echo getpos(".")[1]` to get this line number then use autocmd to test if this line equal the last line number (`nu` for count all line number)

```
function TestIfLastLine()
  if echo getpos(".")[1] ==nu 
  then
    set listchars=eol:¶
  else
     set listchars=eol:\ " I'm use space here
  endif
endfunction
```